# Java - Calculating durations with a factorized Time in mills - Math help needed

Tags: java, math, time, epoch, calculation

**Hello peeps!**

*Before I write about my question, pls pay attention, that I am not a professional developer or educated. I learned all my java knowledge from Web or learning by doing, so my methods may not be the best practice.*

I need help with the following problem:

In **Java** i am running an "companion application" for an online Game.

The "in-game Time" can be easily calculated with a Constant I have in an interface:

```
  final double EORZEA_CONSTANT = 20.571428571428573;
  final long MIN_1 = 60000L;
  final long HOUR_1 = 3600000L;
  final long CORRECTOR = (HOUR_1 / 2);
  final long DAY_1 = 86400000L;
  final long WEEK_1 = 604800000L;

  final double EORZEA_CONSTANT = 20.571428571428573;
```

So the calculation looks like the following:

```
long y = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() * EORZEA_CONSTANT);
minutes = (int) ((y / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
hours = (int) ((y / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
```

like this can display the current in-game daytime (24hrs)

Now my mathematical problem:

I need to **determine the duration until the next 14 or 16 hour** (or whatever) point of time **in this factorized time**. If this point is reached, the next point with the same daytime needs to be calculated and so on.

**The durations need to be reconverted to the Local unfactorized time**, to show how long it takes in "earth time" until this in-game time is reached.

[image]

If the time wasn't factorized I would use something like this:

```
 LocalDate next = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
 LocalDateTime e = LocalDateTime.of(next, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
 long x = e.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond() * 1000;
 long y = x + (HOUR_1 * 17);
```

But I don't think this will work with the factorized time.

I appreciate every little hint, maybe I am thinking too complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t do any math yourself. Let java.time do all math, both for real time and for in-game time.

Comment: Do you understand that days are not always 24 hours long in political time? (I cannot understand if you are strictly using UTC time or local political time.)

Comment: By the way, use `java.time.Duration` for your spans of time unattached to the timeline.  Less math for you to perform. `Duration MIN_1 = Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ) ;` And use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal prime meridian of UTC, “in UTC”. I cannot help further as I cannot grasp this “factorized time”, “EarthTime”, and “in-game time” of yours.

Comment: @Ole how can I use the Java.time math with the factorized time?

Comment: @BasilBourque to understand what the OP calls "factorized time", think of a game in which time goes at a faster pace than real time. Every 7 hours of real time, the time inside the game moves forward 6 days. Hence the factor of 20.57.. to convert from one to the other. The problem here is that `java.time` cannot round up to the next midnight etc. in "game time" as that would involve rounding up to the next multiple of 20.57.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. 1 hour game time is in real time 2 minutes and 55 seconds (likely)

Comment: There are several webpages doing this stuff so it’s possible. My brain just won’t find the solution to this

Comment: One idea is to use `ZonedDateTime` in the system default time zone (or the time zone the user wants) for earth time and `OffsetDateTime` in UTC for game time so the player doesn’t need to deal with summer time (DST) in the game. Using your multiplication of epoch time for conversion gives game times after year 3000, it’s probably OK? Game time math is exactly the same as real time math.

Comment: Conversion could be `OffsetDateTime gameOdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.round(earthZdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() * EORZEA_CONSTANT)).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);`. And the other way: `earthZdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.round(gameOdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() / EORZEA_CONSTANT)).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());`. I’d consider something like `EORZEA_TIME_FACTOR` as name for the constant, though.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime gameTomorrowAt14 = gameOdt.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(14, 0));`. For “next 14” you will need an if statement to determine whether today at 14 has already been passed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ty all for your hints.

I got the working solution (with little issues I still have to solve) with the following code:

(Maybe some facepalms incoming)

```
int spawnTimeA = item.getTime();
int spawnTimeB = item.getTime() + 12;

if (spawnTimeB == 24) {
  spawnTimeB = 12;
  spawnTimeA = 0;
}

if (spawnTimeB > 24) {
  spawnTimeB = spawnTimeA;
}

OffsetDateTime nexTime = null;
OffsetDateTime gameOdt =
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(Math.round(time * EORZEA_CONSTANT))
        .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

if (gameOdt.getHour() >= spawnTimeA && gameOdt.getHour() < spawnTimeB) {

  nexTime = gameOdt.with(LocalTime.of(spawnTimeB, 0));

} else if (gameOdt.getHour() >= spawnTimeB) {

  nexTime = gameOdt.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(spawnTimeA, 0));

} else {

  nexTime = gameOdt.with(LocalTime.of(spawnTimeA, 0));
}

long inGameDiff = (nexTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli())
    - (gameOdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());

long earthTimeDiff = (long) (inGameDiff / EORZEA_CONSTANT);
```

If you have more hints to make it cleaner, I appreciate every single idea or concept I missed.

Ty all!

Comment: That’s good! If it’s true that your factor can be expressed as 144.0 / 7.0, then I would use `Duration` for the differences. Calculate the difference as `Duration inGameDiff = Duration.between(gameOdt, nexTime);`. Convert to earth time using `Duration earthTimeDiff = inGameDiff.multipliedBy(7).dividedBy(144);`. In one case it converted a game difference of approx. 1 hour 9 minutes 44 seconds to an earth difference of 3 minutes 23 seconds. You can directly add a `Duration` to any datetime object including `ZonedDateTime`. Unfortunately there is no support for dividing a `Duration` by a `double`

Comment: Thank you. For me using longs for the difference may make more sense since all data pulled via JSON from the rest api of the game is provided as epoch times … or am I thinking into a wrong direction?

Comment: You will have to weigh yourself. Personally I find java.time so nice to work with, so I routinely convert all epoch millis that I receive to `Instant`and possibly other classes from there. The code also gets more self explanatory that way. Obviously working in millis is possible, and the multiplication and division by your factor is easier in millis.

Comment: (At work I just submitted a code change for review where I substituted the use of `long` millis with `Duration` also where the millis were kept around for passing to [`BlockingQueue.poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) or other methods not accepting a `Duration`. On one hand I did what I found right, on the other I’m prepared for the discussion whether I overdid it.)